# VS Code explorer shows a directory deleted with a letter "D" next to the directory name

Tags: visual-studio-code

I opened a folder in VSCode, and then I copied another subfolder to that folder and the subfolder showed up in VSCoder explorer. However, the name of the folder is red, with a letter "D" next to it. And all the subfolders under it are greyed, although I can open the files.

Why is that? How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: do you use SCM like git, what does `git status` on terminal show you

Comment: git status shows the folder is deleted

Comment: VSC just shows the output of `git status` in colors and characters, find out why git thinks dir is deleted

Comment: Oh, there is one symbolic link with the same name of the subfolder I tried to move to. Is there any way for me to make use of that symbolic link so that I can move the files to be in that symbolic link?